# Virtual office for a team of freelancers

Tags: virtual-office

I recently heard that some freelancers use virtual offices not only for small team collaboration, but also when negotiating with clients.

What is your experience with it? I would like to hear bad sides of it primarily.

Is it really something that you would recommend any freelancer use?

Also, it would be good you recommend a service you used where I seek most features for lowest price :).

Comment: Hey Peter, as it stands, this sounds like a community poll, which doesn't fit the SE format very well as opinions are hard to vet as answers. I was going to try to edit it, but I'm not sure I can do that on my own without your help. Is there a problem you faced or have seen someone face that you could possibly elaborate on to give this some context? Since we don't have a community of close voters yet, I've put this on hold temporarily to give us time to make some edits. If you edit, please let us know and we'll take a look at opening it up for answers. Hope the tips help! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Hm to be frank, I am not sure how can I make this question with more data since I haven't used virtual office ever. I just heard some guys are using it (read on the Internet) and wanted to see if there is anyone here with first-person experience.